# How to use mongodb and mysql together in a SpringMVC web project

Tags: mongodb, mybatis

In a SpringMVC web project,  I want to use MySQL with MyBatis framework, and use "Spring Data MongoDB" to operating MongoDB, how to combined them，I try to do it ，but failed. Is there any demo code or document can give me instructions. 
thanks

Comment: what do you mean combine them?

Comment: @ koulini  Two data sources，one is MYSQL, another is MongoDB

Comment: any particular error you are facing?

Comment: Any solution for this ?